# Node Async.each http.get request not firing/waiting

Tags: node.js, http, asynchronous

I have a larger process running through a large collection of locations/devices in an API response and I'm trying to get to individual devices and turn that into a response my target system will understand. However it seems my inline HTTP request is not firing.

I've tried moving the callback out of the 'end' event, but I'm not even getting the logging for earlier up in the function. The only logging output I get is the "getting status for zone xyz"

```
async.each(tempSystem.zones, function(zone, zoneCallback) {
    var applianceDiscovered = {};
    console.log("getting status for zone", zone);
    var options = {
        host: host,
        path: '/webapi/' + zone.zoneId + '/status',
        headers: {'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + accessToken}
    };
    var req = https.get(options, function(res) {
        if (res.statusCode != 200) {
            console.log("error ", res.statusCode);
        }
        console.log(res);
        var bodyChunks = [];
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            bodyChunks.push(chunk);
        });
        res.on('end', function() {
            if (res.statusCode === 200) {
            console.log("get zone status: ", res.statusCode);
            var body = Buffer.concat(bodyChunks);
            var zoneStatus = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log(zoneStatus);
            zoneCallback();
            } else {
                console.log(res.statusCode);
            }
        });
        res.on('error', function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });  
    });
    req.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log("error: ", e);
    });
}, function(err){
    console.log("finished with zones");
});
```

Comment: Most probably an error happens, and this code does not handle any errors.

Comment: What is `tempSystem.zones`? An array or an object? `async.each` takes an array.

Comment: @TamasHegedus apologies, I had it previously. Added it back.

Comment: @cartant yes it's an array. I get a logging of "getting status for zone" for each item.

Comment: You need to add an `on('error', ...)` for the `req`.

Comment: @cartant thanks for the help so far. I've edited the above to include more error handling. I get no other output other than "getting status for zone" for each item in the array.

Comment: What is the format of `host`? Does it really contain *just* the hostname and not start with `'https://'` or contain a port number appended to the end like `':443'`? Also, have you tried starting a packet capture to see if the server responds to the requests (even the initial TLS handshakes) at all?

Comment: Depending on how long the overall function takes to run, sometimes I'll see the responses in my log AFTER the callbacks are done.

Comment: @mscdex also, yes host is a global variable and works fine in other functions that are formatted the same calling the same API.

The only difference here is I'm trying to call it multiple times for each zone, which can vary by the individual user account (hence the oauth token).

Comment: Which node versions have you tried? Have you tried explicitly opting out of the global `https.Agent` by setting `agent: false` to see if that helps at all?

Comment: @mscdex It's Amazon Lambda, so it's on Node 4.3. I also just tried opting out of the global agent, I don't get different results. I'll keep looking at it today.